# XAMPP Infinite Repeated Server Pulls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, xampp, infinite-loop

In building an Android group chat application through the use of websockets and XAMPP, the  group messaging user screen is continually displaying only the first message in the database, over and over again, until I stop running the application. Note that the repeating of the message only occurs in the SQLite client app and not in the MySQL server database (where there is only one instance of that one message).

Referencing the Logcat output for the Android app, it shows all the group messages that are received, so it sees all those in the MySQL database for that group, but then only displays the first message repeatedly in the users screen until I kill the application. As well, in using nearly the same code for the individual chat, ie. one-to-one chat, works just fine, but group chat will infinitely pull and insert the first message in the database to the users screen.

Is there a way to prevent such infinite repeated actions for group chat as it connects to the server? Or perhaps a way to communicate to the server that the messages are up to date and no longer need to pull the same list of messages?

My code for both sending and receiving a group message if it helps: (BroadcastReceiver is near the bottom)

```
public class GroupMessaging extends Activity {

    private static final int MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT = 0;
    public String username;
    public String groupname;

    private EditText messageText;
    private EditText messageHistoryText;
    private Button sendMessageButton;
    private Manager imService;
    private InfoOfGroup group = new InfoOfGroup();
    private StorageManipulater localstoragehandler;
    private Cursor dbCursor;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder) service).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(GroupMessaging.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.message); // messaging_screen);

        messageHistoryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);

        messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

        messageText.requestFocus();

        sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);

        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        group.groupName = extras.getString(InfoOfGroup.GROUPNAME);
        group.groupId = extras.getString(InfoOfGroup.GROUPID);
        String msg = extras.getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_TEXT);

        setTitle("Group: " + group.groupName);

        // Retrieve the information
        localstoragehandler = new StorageManipulater(this);
        dbCursor = localstoragehandler.groupGet(group.groupId);

        if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0) {

            int noOfScorer = 0;
            dbCursor.moveToFirst();

            while ((!dbCursor.isAfterLast())
                    && noOfScorer < dbCursor.getCount()) {
                noOfScorer++;

                // String 2: Username
                // String 3: Message
                this.appendToMessageHistory(dbCursor.getString(2),
                        dbCursor.getString(3));
                dbCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        localstoragehandler.close();

        if (msg != null) {
            // Then friends username and message, not equal to null
            this.appendToMessageHistory(group.groupId, msg);
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                    .cancel((group.groupId + msg).hashCode());
        }

        // The send button
        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            CharSequence message;
            Handler handler = new Handler();

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                message = messageText.getText();
                if (message.length() > 0) {

                    appendToMessageHistory(imService.getUsername(),
                            message.toString());

                    // *****************PROBLEM MAY BE
                    // HERE******************************
                    localstoragehandler.groupInsert(imService.getUsername(),
                            group.groupId, message.toString());

                    messageText.setText("");
                    Thread thread = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                                if (imService.sendGroupMessage(group.groupId,
                                        group.groupName, message.toString()) == null) {

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                        public void run() {

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            // showDialog(MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT);
                                        }

                                    });
                                }
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();

                }

            }
        });

        messageText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == 66) {
                    sendMessageButton.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        int message = -1;
        switch (id) {
        case MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT:
            message = R.string.message_cannot_be_sent;
            break;
        }

        if (message == -1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(GroupMessaging.this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                                }
                            }).create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(groupMessageReceiver);
        unbindService(mConnection);

        ControllerOfGroup.setActiveGroup(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bindService(new Intent(GroupMessaging.this, MessagingService.class),
                mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(MessagingService.TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE);

        registerReceiver(groupMessageReceiver, i);

        ControllerOfGroup.setActiveGroup(group.groupName);

    }

    // For receiving messages form other users...
    public class GroupMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            String username = extra.getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.FROM_USER);
            String groupId = extra.getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.TO_GROUP_ID);
            String message = extra
                    .getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_TEXT);

            // *************************OR HERE******************************
            if (username != null && message != null) {
                if (group.groupId.equals(groupId)) {
                    appendToMessageHistory(username, message);
                    localstoragehandler.groupInsert(username, groupId, message);

                } else {
                    if (message.length() > 15) {
                        message = message.substring(0, 15);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(GroupMessaging.this,
                            username + " says '" + message + "'",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Build receiver object to accept messages
    private GroupMessageReceiver groupMessageReceiver = new GroupMessageReceiver();

    // Setting username and message to the message box
    public void appendToMessageHistory(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {
            messageHistoryText.append(username + ":\n");
            messageHistoryText.append(message + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (localstoragehandler != null) {
            localstoragehandler.close();
        }
        if (dbCursor != null) {
            dbCursor.close();
        }
    }
```

MessagingService Class:

```
public class MessagingService extends Service implements Manager, Updater {
    // private NotificationManager mNM;

    public static String USERNAME;
    public static final String TAKE_MESSAGE = "Take_Message";
    public static final String FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Friend List";
    public static final String MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Message List";

    public static final String TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE = "Take_Group_Message";
    public static final String GROUP_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Group List";
    public static final String GROUP_MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Group Message List";

    public ConnectivityManager conManager = null;
    private final int UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD = 15000;

    private String rawFriendList = new String();
    private String rawMessageList = new String();

    private String rawGroupList = new String();
    private String rawGroupMessageList = new String();

    SocketerInterface socketOperator = new Socketer(this);

    private final IBinder mBinder = new IMBinder();
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String groupname;
    private boolean authenticatedUser = false;
    // timer to take the updated data from server
    private Timer timer;

    private StorageManipulater localstoragehandler;

    private NotificationManager mNM;

    public class IMBinder extends Binder {
        public Manager getService() {
            return MessagingService.this;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        localstoragehandler = new StorageManipulater(this);

        conManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        new StorageManipulater(this);

        // Timer is used to take the friendList info every UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD;
        timer = new Timer();

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Random random = new Random();
                int tryCount = 0;
                while (socketOperator.startListening(10000 + random
                        .nextInt(20000)) == 0) {
                    tryCount++;
                    if (tryCount > 10) {
                        // if it can't listen a port after trying 10 times, give
                        // up...
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private void showNotification(String username, String msg) {
        // Set the icon, scrolling text and TIMESTAMP
        String title = "AndroidIM: You got a new Message! (" + username + ")";

        String text = username + ": "
                + ((msg.length() < 5) ? msg : msg.substring(0, 5) + "...");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(text);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, IndividualMessaging.class);
        i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.USERNAME, username);
        i.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.MESSAGETEXT, msg);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mBuilder.setContentText("New message from " + username + ": " + msg);

        // Send the notification.
        // We use a layout id because it is a unique number. We use it later to
        // cancel.
        mNM.notify((username + msg).hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public String sendMessage(String username, String tousername, String message)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8")
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8")
                + "&to=" + URLEncoder.encode(tousername, "UTF-8") + "&message="
                + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8") + "&action="
                + URLEncoder.encode("sendMessage", "UTF-8") + "&";
        Log.i("PARAMS", params);
        return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);
    }


    private String getFriendList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // after authentication, server replies with friendList xml

        // Has the friend and group and message(s) xml
        rawFriendList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawFriendList != null) {
            this.parseFriendInfo(rawFriendList);
        }
        return rawFriendList;
    }

    private String getMessageList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        rawMessageList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawMessageList != null) {
            this.parseMessageInfo(rawMessageList);
        }
        return rawMessageList;
    }

    private String getGroupList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        rawGroupList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawGroupList != null) {
            this.parseGroupInfo(rawGroupList);
        }
        return rawGroupList;
    }

    private String getGroupMessageList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        rawGroupMessageList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawGroupMessageList != null) {
            this.parseGroupInfo(rawGroupMessageList);
        }
        return rawGroupMessageList;
    }


    public String authenticateUser(String usernameText, String passwordText)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this.username = usernameText;
        this.password = passwordText;

        this.authenticatedUser = false;

        String result = null;

        result = this.getFriendList(); // socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username,
                                        // password));

        if (result != null && !result.equals(LoggingIn.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)) {
            // if user is authenticated then return string from server is not
            // equal to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
            this.authenticatedUser = true;
            rawFriendList = result;
            USERNAME = this.username;

            // For Friends
            Intent i = new Intent(FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.FRIEND_LIST, rawFriendList);
            sendBroadcast(i);

            // For Groups
            Intent iG = new Intent(GROUP_LIST_UPDATED);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroup.GROUP_LIST, rawGroupList);
            sendBroadcast(iG);

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // rawFriendList = IMService.this.getFriendList();
                        // sending friend list
                        Intent i = new Intent(FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED);
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED);
                        Intent i3 = new Intent(GROUP_LIST_UPDATED);
                        Intent i4 = new Intent(GROUP_MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED);

                        String tmp = MessagingService.this.getFriendList();
                        String tmp2 = MessagingService.this.getMessageList();

                        String tmp3 = MessagingService.this.getGroupList();
                        String tmp4 = MessagingService.this
                                .getGroupMessageList();

                        // For friends
                        if (tmp != null) {
                            i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.FRIEND_LIST, tmp);
                            sendBroadcast(i);
                            Log.i("friend list broadcast sent ", "");

                            if (tmp2 != null) {
                                i2.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.MESSAGE_LIST, tmp2);
                                sendBroadcast(i2);
                                Log.i("friend list broadcast sent ", "");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i("friend list returned null", "");
                        }

                        // Changed to i3 and i4 for the intents created...
                        if (tmp3 != null) {
                            i3.putExtra(InfoOfGroup.GROUP_LIST, tmp3);
                            sendBroadcast(i3);
                            Log.i("group list broadcast sent ", "");

                            if (tmp4 != null) {
                                i4.putExtra(
                                        InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_LIST,
                                        tmp4);
                                sendBroadcast(i4);
                                Log.i("group list broadcast sent ", "");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i("group list returned null", "");
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD, UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void messageReceived(String username, String message) {

        // FriendInfo friend = FriendController.getFriendInfo(username);
        InfoOfMessage msg = IndividualMessageController.checkMessage(username);
        if (msg != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(TAKE_MESSAGE);

            i.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.USERID, msg.userid);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.MESSAGETEXT, msg.messagetext);
            sendBroadcast(i);
            String activeFriend = ControllerOfFriend.getActiveFriend();
            if (activeFriend == null || activeFriend.equals(username) == false) {
                localstoragehandler.insert(username, this.getUsername(),
                        message.toString());
                showNotification(username, message);
            }

            Log.i("TAKE_MESSAGE broadcast sent by im service", "");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void groupMessageReceived(String username, String groupId,
            String message) {

        // FriendInfo friend = FriendController.getFriendInfo(username);
        InfoOfGroupMessage msg = GroupMessageController.checkMessage(username);
        if (msg != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE);

            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroupMessage.FROM_USER, msg.fromUser);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroupMessage.TO_GROUP_ID, msg.toGroupId);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_TEXT, msg.messageText);

            sendBroadcast(i);

        }

        Log.i("TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE broadcast sent by im service", "");
    }

    private String getAuthenticateUserParams(String usernameText,
            String passwordText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String params = "username="
                + URLEncoder.encode(usernameText, "UTF-8")
                + "&password="
                + URLEncoder.encode(passwordText, "UTF-8")
                + "&action="
                + URLEncoder.encode("authenticateUser", "UTF-8")
                + "&port="
                + URLEncoder.encode(
                        Integer.toString(socketOperator.getListeningPort()),
                        "UTF-8") + "&";

        return params;
    }

    public void setUserKey(String value) {
    }

    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        return conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

    public boolean isUserAuthenticated() {
        return authenticatedUser;
    }

    public String getLastRawFriendList() {
        return this.rawFriendList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("IMService is being destroyed", "...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void exit() {
        timer.cancel();
        socketOperator.exit();
        socketOperator = null;
        this.stopSelf();
    }

    public String signUpUser(String usernameText, String passwordText,
            String emailText) {
        String params = "username=" + usernameText + "&password="
                + passwordText + "&action=" + "signUpUser" + "&email="
                + emailText + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        // This is the output of the datastream from the server ie. <data>
        // (bunch of data...etc) </data>
        return result;
    }

    public String addNewFriendRequest(String friendUsername) {
        String params = "username=" + this.username + "&password="
                + this.password + "&action=" + "addNewFriend"
                + "&friendUserName=" + friendUsername + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        return result;
    }

    public String sendFriendsReqsResponse(String approvedFriendNames,
            String discardedFriendNames) {
        String params = "username=" + this.username + "&password="
                + this.password + "&action=" + "responseOfFriendReqs"
                + "&approvedFriends=" + approvedFriendNames
                + "&discardedFriends=" + discardedFriendNames + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        return result;

    }


    public void updateData(InfoOfMessage[] messages, InfoOfFriend[] friends,
            InfoOfGroup[] groups, InfoOfGroupMessage[] groupMessages,
            InfoOfFriend[] unApprovedFriends, String userKey) {
        this.setUserKey(userKey);
        // FriendController.
        IndividualMessageController.setMessagesInfo(messages);
        // Log.i("MESSAGEIMSERVICE","messages.length="+messages.length);
        GroupMessageController.setMessagesInfo(groupMessages);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < messages.length) {
            messageReceived(messages[i].userid, messages[i].messagetext);

            i++;
        }

        int j = 0;
        while (j < groupMessages.length) {
            groupMessageReceived(groupMessages[j].fromUser,
                    groupMessages[j].toGroupId, groupMessages[j].messageText);
            j++;
        }

        // For individual chat
        ControllerOfFriend.setFriendsInfo(friends);
        ControllerOfFriend.setUnapprovedFriendsInfo(unApprovedFriends);

        // For group chat
        ControllerOfGroup.setGroupsInfo(groups);
        // ControllerOfGroup.setUnapprovedGroupsInfo(unapprovedGroups);
    }

    // ************GENERAL METHODS FOR THE GROUP CHAT************

    @Override
    public String createNewGroup(String userName, String groupName)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8")
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8")
                + "&action=" + "createGroup" + "&groupName=" + groupName + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String addGroupMember() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String sendGroupMessage(String toGroupId, String toGroupName,
            String messageText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8")
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8")
                + "&toGroupId=" + URLEncoder.encode(toGroupId, "UTF-8")
                + "&messageText=" + URLEncoder.encode(messageText, "UTF-8")
                + "&action=" + URLEncoder.encode("sendGroupMessage", "UTF-8")
                + "&";
        Log.i("PARAMS", params);
        return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

    }

    @Override
    public String getGroupName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.groupname;
    }

}
```

Comment: use asmack library for better exprience

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I looked into that option, but it lacked the control over the content that I wanted. As for my app, everything is working fine aside from this little glitch. Any insight into where the error may be occuring?